# Jquery .validation() not performing like it should

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-validate

I am trying to carry out the tutorial seen here: http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/validation/

I have in my site.js:

```
Template.inquiry.onRendered(function(){
    $('.request-form').validate();
});
```

In the inquiry template, I have:

```
<template name="inquiry">
    <form class="request-form" id="request-form" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="row uniform 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

However, when I type in an invalid email, the .validate() function does not do what it says in the tutorial (spits out an error message).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Using the id instead of class worked.  Weird.  If you add an answer I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: How you select the form, `id`, `class`, or any other jQuery selector makes no difference to the `.validate()` method, unless you had *multiple matching* forms on the page ... in that case, `.validate()` would only work on the *first* instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can remember, for the jQuery plugin validate work well, you should add the validations (required / maxlength) on your form, so it will be reproduced in jQuery.

Try to use `$('#request-form').validate();`. Getting the elementy by id, instead of class.

Comment: How you select the form, `id`, `class`, or any other jQuery selector makes no difference to the `.validate()` method, unless you had multiple matching forms on the page ... in that case, `.validate()` would only work on the *first* instance.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/eavmn6y5/